# How to Improve SQL Azure Query Performance

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I am using EF 6 to execute a `SqlQuery`, which is a `SELECT` statement returning 47 columns with a max of 500 rows. The query has eight `LEFT JOIN` statements.

In my local environment, the query only takes around 300 ms, as indicated in Express Profiler.

On SQL Azure, the same query can take 4800 ms, as indicated in the Query Performance > Query Plan Details section on the SQL Azure portal. The tier is S0.

At the time of testing, there was only one local session. There are probably only less than 10 sessions when accessing SQL Azure. It's on the development environment only.

What can be the causes of the difference, and what can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: Show us the query, execution plan, how many sessions are running on your PC vs. SQL Azure, what performance tier to you have on SQL Azure, etc.

Comment: @ta.speot.is How can I get the execution plan?

Comment: press Ctrl+M before running the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL azure there are many things to consider if a query is not running as expected.Unlike normal server,SQL azure preformance is expressed in form of DTUs  which simply mean amount of transactions that can be handled based on performance tier..To quote from MDSN.., a performance level with 5 DTUs has five times more power than a performance level with 1 DTU...

Can you also check sys.dm_db_resource_stats DMV usage and see the metrics state,if any metric is showing values more than 90%,it means your peformance level may needs to be upgraded...

You also  can run same query in loop and capture data from sys.dm_exec_requests to see any signs of waits and blocking..

```
  select top 10* from sys.dm_exec_requests 
where session_id=<<sessionid from where you are running the query>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. As you can probably tell, I have very little experience with SQL Azure performance tuning.